# use bash to rename a file with spaces and regex

Tags: bash, file-rename

If I have a file name with spaces and a random set of numbers that looks like this:

```
file name1234.csv
```

I want to rename it  to this (assuming date is previously specified):

```
file_name_${date}.csv
```

I am able to do it like this:

```
mv 'file name'*'.csv file_name_${date}.csv
```

However, in a situation that 'file name*.csv' can actually match multiple files, I want to specify that it's 'file name[random numbers].csv'

I've searched around and can't find any relevant answers.

Comment: Could you use `find` to do a regular expression search with a pattern like `file name\d+\.csv`?

Comment: When `'file name '*'.csv` matches multiple files you're probably going to want to handle this differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what is called a "pathname expansion", to match one or more digits:

```
+([0-9])
```

A functional script could be like this one:

```
date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')

shopt -s extglob nullglob

for f in 'file name'+([[:digit:]]).csv; do
    file="${f%%[0-9]*}"
    echo mv "$f" "${file// /_}_${date}.csv"
done
```

*Warning*: all files found will be renamed to just one name, make sure that that is what you want before removing the echo.

To activate the extended version of "Pathname Expansion" we use `shopt -s extglob`.
To avoid the case where no file is matched, we also need the `nullglob` set.
We can set the positional arguments to the result of the above expansion.
Then we loop over all files found to change each of their names.
The `${f%%[0-9]*}` removes all from the digits to the end.
The `${file// /_}` replaces spaces with underscores.
The `mv` is not actually done with the script presented because of the `echo`.

If after running a test, you want the change(s) performed, remove the `echo`.

Answer (score -1):

### Use Extended Globs and Parameter Expansion

You can do what you want with Bash [extended globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and a few [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), without resorting to external or non-standard utilities.

```
date="2016-11-21"

shopt -s extglob
for file in 'file name'+([[:digit:]]).csv; do
    newfile="${file%%[0-9]*}"
    newfile="${newfile// /_}"
    mv "$file" "${newfile}_${date}.csv"
done
```